# Using function to for-in loop through object to change values then return result

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop, hasownproperty

I'm building a function that uses a for-in loop to go through any object, change it's values (whether they be a number, string or boolean) to a single specific string, then output it. I've been through a bunch of existing questions which have helped me gain a general understanding of for-in loops. I've been trying to figure out how to make the function  make the change then return the new values. Here's what I have so far:

```
var switcharoo = function(whateverObject){
  for (var i in whateverObject){
    if (whateverObject.hasOwnProperty(i)){
  alert(i + "redacted" + whateverObject[i]);
    }
  }
return whateverObject;
};
```

I understand the framework I've set up for the function. I understand the structure of the for-in loop. I also understand the importance of the hasOwnProperty part. Now I'm lost... the

```
alert(i + "this is a string" + whateverObject[i]);
```

line, I can't wrap my head around. I got it from a question here on StackOverflow. The return whateverObject line is just my best effort to output the result. So how would I run through an object and change all the values to a specific string?

Bonus question: How would I tweak this function to search for true/false values and remove only the false ones?

Comment: You are not assigning any string to any of the object properties. Besides i would suggest using  Object.keys() for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is... you're not changing anything at all :D

`alert` just displays the value, but does nothing else.

```
var switcharoo = function(whateverObject){
  for (var i in whateverObject){
    if (whateverObject.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      alert(i + "redacted" + whateverObject[i]);

      // Assign value to this key in whateverObject
      whateverObject[i] = 'redacted';

    }
  }
  return whateverObject;
};
```

> How would I tweak this function to search for true/false values and remove only the false ones?

Now for some advanced JavaScript. You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of an object's keys. Use that array to loop through all the keys in the object. You can then use `reduce` to construct an object with only the keys that don't have `false` values.

```
function switcharoo(object){
  return Object.keys(object).reduce(function(allTrue, key){
    if(object[key] !== false) allTrue[key] = object[key];
    return allTrue;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: so you use reduce to rake through all of an objects 'keys' using whatever stipulations you create (allTrue, in this instance) and only work with whatever meets those stipulations?

Comment: @Kyle `reduce` is like `forEach` except you get the return value of the previous iteration. In this case, it is used to carry through the initial value `{}` as `allTrue`, appending each non-false key-value pair along the way. The last iteration's return becomes the return of `reduce`.

Comment: Got it, I'm still getting used to the idea that you can declare a new variable (i.e. allTrue) in the middle of a block of code. If a key has no value, is it false? I'm getting an error still because one of the keys has no value and is included in my output when it shouldn't...

Comment: @Kyle `allTrue` didn't come from thin air. It's the `{}` at the end, the "initial value" of `reduce`. Also, instead of checking for `false`, why not compare to `true` (`object[key] === true`).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```js
var switcharoo = (o,s) => Object.keys(o).reduce((p,k) => {p[k] = s; return p},{}),
         myObj = {a: 1,
                  b: _ => console.log(this.a),
                  c: {x: 3,
                      y: "hi there",
                      z: [1,2,3]
                     }
                 };
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(switcharoo(myObj, "stractassineboom"), null, 2) + "</pre>");
```